How to use a relay to replace a sensor to send signal?
I might know how to do it, but not so sure about it, cause I forgot how I did it last time and fear that I would burn the machine's interface if I do it wrong this time, so help me to eliminate the fear.
The client's printer uses a light sensor(NPN) that will trigger the printing action, but now they want to manually trigger it via another machine's relay(Normal Open), so they want me to hook it up.
So I brought a 3 wire connector which is the same wire pattern to the sensor, you know, brown, blue, black, I will connect this side to the printer to replace the orginal sensor.
The problem is which two wires should I hook to the relay, I guess the blue and black, right?
Here's more information about this setup.
The Machine's PLC controlls the 24v relay through one of its ouput(Y1 on the PLC), and the sensor is a 24v photoelectric sensor, NPN type.
Please let me know what else should I provide in the comment.

wire colors are meaningless ... what are you connecting to what?

my bad, I added a picture for easier understanding.

@Neil_UK Hi, I'm also clueless here, the sensor will be removed, so it left a interface with 3 wires to the printer, and I just want to know what can I do send the signal with this interface, I thought a relay is needed here

Hi, you will need to provide some additional information. What do you mean by NPN light sensor? Is it an optocoupler? Also what are the system voltages of relay and the sensor?

@SRomie My bad, I will edit the question

@castiel One more thing to consider. The relay will sink much more current than the phototransistor. Can the PLC source it?

@SRomie I have full control of the PLC, I just don't know how to do it

@castiel We cannot help how to connect them unless you tell which wire of the sensor is which regarding the supply, ground, and NPN output.

@castiel Do you have a multimeter of some type? If so, measure the voltage blue to black wire, and brown to black wire, under the following three conditions (so a total of 6 measurements) a) sensor not connected b) sensor connected but not triggered c) sensor connected and triggered. That may give us enough information to help you.

Keep in mind that individual parts/machines can use wire colors in non-standard ways.
Having said that, with most industrial sensors, the standard wire colors are:

Brown: +24 VDC (Pin 1 of an M12 connector)
Blue: 0 VDC (Pin 3)
Black: signal (Pin 4)

With an NPN sensor, when the sensor is activated, it switches the signal (Black) wire to be connected to 0 volts (Blue).
So my guess is that if you connect the Blue and Black wires to the contact of the relay, then when the “Machine” energizes the coil of the relay, the “Printer” will respond the same way as it did when the sensor was activated.
